# REST Assured async - cannot find method

Tags: java, rest-assured

I'm trying to set timeout for REST Assured request.
acording the documentations the async method implement it.
however, my IDE can't find this method in the source code.
what i'm missing here?
here is the code:

```
Response response=given().
                body("a string").
                when().
                async().with().timeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS).post("/stringBody").
                then().
                body(equalTo("a string"));
```

REST Assured docs: https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#asynchronous-requests

Comment: It's unclear what IDE , Java Runtime, Environment are you using.

Comment: i'm using Intellij, but I dont think it's relevant. i'm sure it will happen on Eclipse also. 
i'm using Java 8.

Comment: Did you find the solution ?

Answer (score 2):

The `async` method only applicable for the [Spring MockMvc module](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#spring-mock-mvc-module). I.e. if you're specifically testing Spring applications and the using RestAssuredMockMvc API instead of the RestAssured API. The `async` method is thus not available when using the standard RestAssured API.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
given().config(RestAssuredConfig.config() .httpClient(HttpClientConfig.httpClientConfig() .setParam("http.connection.timeout",1000)))
```